# I have a UITableView how do I "GET" the text from the UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm developing an iPhone app and have a cell object.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But how do I GET the text from that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a cell that was created with one of the system cell types, it has a `UILabel *` member called `textLabel`. If you've created a custom cell type, you should set the `tag` property of the relevant view (in IB or in code), then retrieve it using the `viewWithTag:` method on your cell.